# Change nginx response body with reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Trying to change the content of a page I'm reverse proxying through an nginx server. I've tried using nginx_substitutions_filter with no luck.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how it's down. For example - want to replace all instances of `foo` with `bar` on `http://lotsoffoos.com`

```
location / {

  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_pass          https://lotsoffoos.com;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  subs_filter_types  text/html text/css text/xml;
  subs_filter “foo” “bar" gir;

}
```

Comment: You've activated the module in nginx, right? Do you also mind explaining why you are trying to do this at the nginx level?

Comment: I have, compiled from source. I'm trying to rebrand a customer facing portal on a platform that is still integrating the feature.

Comment: You seem to have `“` fancy quotes instead of `"` plain quotes

Comment: It works exactly as put in the question (assuming those bad quotes are just typos) - given [your subsequent question](http://serverfault.com/questions/648428/location-directive-in-nginx-for-root-only-nested-in) are requests hitting that location block? Demonstrating the error would help.